# How to I add up values contained in span tags with Cypress.io?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, cypress

I need to go through a group of  tags that have a specific class associated with them and have a text value.

For example. I want to take all of the text under the spans that have text, add those numbers up, and store them in a variable to compare them with something else on the screen:

```
<span class="property-ut text-old">12.50</span>
<span class="property-ut text-old"></span>
<span class="property-ut text-old"></span>
<span class="property-ut text-old">.50</span>
<span class="property-ut text-old">1.50</span>
```

I'm expecting to store the value of 14.50 into a variable and compare that with some other value on the screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Created a local server with above html `span` tag in a div with id `#mySpantext`. Used jquery `each` function to iterate through each span class and calculated the `sum` of span text as below;

```
var sum = 0;
Cypress.$('.text-old').each(function() {
  sum += +Cypress.$(this).text()||0;
});
```

The complete cypress test as written below;

```
describe('Sum of the span element values in Cypress', function() {
  it('Sum of the span element', function() {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/test')
    cy.get('#mySpantext').find('span').then(() => {     
    var sum = 0;
    Cypress.$('.text-old').each(function() {
      sum += +Cypress.$(this).text()||0;
    });
    cy.log("Total sum of all span elements:"+sum);
    expect(sum).to.equal(14.5)
    })
  })
})
```

Test results as given below, on right-hand side, highlighted the span text values; 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I always forget that I can user Jquery with this.

Comment: I am having a new problem.  There are 2 more sections that contain this information. the format is like <div id="mainThing"><div uib-accordion-header><h4>Cars</h4><span class="property-ut text-old">12.50</span>
<span class="property-ut text-old"></span> </div><div uib-accordion-header><h4>Planes</h4><span class="property-ut text-old">12.50</span>
<span class="property-ut text-old"></span></div></div> How Can I just select the values from either the Cars section or Planes section?

Comment: Try the following way to find, u can repeat the same for planes. I have run the test and its passing..`cy.get('h4:contains("Cars")').next('span').invoke('text')
    .then((text)=>{
      const carsValue = text; 
      expect(carsValue).to.equal('12.50');`
    })`

Answer (score 2):

No need to use jQuery here, Cypress has an 'each' method: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Syntax

The amount will be represented as text, so you'll need to convert to not concat. This also strips commas in case you have values > 1,000

```
let sum = 0
let expectedVal = 14.50
cy.get('.old-text').each(($li, index, $lis) => {
  sum += parseFloat($li.text().replace(',', ''))
  if(index == $lis.length - 1) {
    assert.equal(expectedVal, sum, 'Expected value equals sum of each line item')
  }
}
```

Be careful with the accepted answer, I was unable to get it to fail with a different value than expected...